# conversion of POJO code into jar file for uploading in Drools Guvnor

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

I want to upload my POJO code into Drools Guvnor. Problem here is POJO code should be only in .jar file. How would I convert my POJO code into jar file so that I can upload it easily in Drools Guvnor.

Comment: Where do you have your POJO model right now?

Comment: I just have POJO code used in Eclipse for Drools Coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend learning the basics of Java before delving into Drools and Guvnor!

Here's the Java tutorial on creating Jar files:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

... but you would be better off using Maven to do your builds:

http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: I second @Steve on this, but instead of maven I'd recommend [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) as it's simpler to use.

Comment: I mention Maven because all the Drools projects are built with it, so it's easier to build the example projects. Also Drools 6 (Workbench in particular) has been tightly integrated with it. This doesn't mean that Gradle won't be usable with v6 projects, but sticking with Maven is likely to make it somewhat easier to follow tutorials and use Workbench. I'm curious to see whether this focus on Maven will make things difficult for Gradle users, or whether it will be relatively frictionless.

Answer (score 0):

Take your all POJO files that are to be converted into .jar file,right click them and export it as jar, name and locate your jar file
.Now, Move to drools guvnor -->select the package-->Assets-->Model,open it and  upload that jar here